# SQL Server 2000 - Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

For our application, we using SQL Server 2000 & MySQL. I want to update the MySQL database if any modifications in SQL Server 2000. For this, I have created the Linked Server for MySQL. It works fine, but inside the trigger it shows the error message like

> [OLE/DB provider returned
>   message: [MySQL][ODBC 3.51
>   Driver]Optional feature not
>   supported]
>   Msg 7391, Level 16,
>   State 1, Procedure ,
>   Line 6
>   The operation could not be performed because the OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' was unable to begin a distributed transaction."

And this is my trigger,

```
alter trigger upd_test_enum
on mtest
for insert
as
begin
   insert into emsdev...test_enum (id, name, is_active) values (4, 'Test4', 0)
end
```

Please help me.

Regard,
Mubarak

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message. With this, you never need any `<br/>` in your post!

Answer (score 3):

I had to do a few things to get it working. Also using a Win2K SQL server and importing data from MySql.

One thing we did was to install the **3.51.22** version of the MySql ODBC driver (mysql-connector-odbc-3.51.22-win32.msi).

Then the following article was very helpful: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx

The main thing was to switch off transactions as well as to refer to the **DSN** when creating a Linked Server. For ease of reference I'll copy and paste the instructions from the SQLServerCentral article in this post below:

> Creating a Linked Server in SSMS for a MySQL database
>
> 1. Download the MySQL ODBC driver from mysql.com
> 2. Install MySQL ODBC driver on Server where SQL Server resides  -Double Click Windows Installer file and follow directions.
> 3. Create a DSN using the MySQL ODBC driver Start-> Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)  -Click
>      on the System DSN tab  -Click Add  -Select the MySQL ODBC Driver 
>      -Click Finish On the Login Tab:  -Type a descriptive name for your DSN.  -Type the server name or IP Address into the Server text box. 
>      -Type the username needed to connect to the MySQL database into the user text box.  -Type the password needed to connect to the MySQL
>      database into the password text box.  -Select the database you'd like
>      to start in. On the Advance Tab: Under Flags 1:  -Check Don't Optimize
>      column width.  -Check Return Matching Rows  -Check Allow Big Results 
>      -Check Use Compressed protocol  -Check BIGINT columns to INT  -Check Safe Under Flags 2:  -Check Don't Prompt Upon Connect  -Check Ignore #
>      in Table Name Under Flags 3:  -Check Return Table Names for
>      SQLDescribeCol  -Check Disable Transactions Now Test your DSN by
>      Clicking the Test button
> 4. Create a Linked Server in SSMS for the MySQL database SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio -> Expand Server Objects  -Right Click Linked
>      Servers -> Select New Linked Server On the General Page:  -Linked
>      Server: Type the Name for your Linked Server  -Server Type: Select
>      Other Data Source  -Provider: Select Microsoft OLE DB Provider for
>      ODBC Drivers  -Product name: Type MySQLDatabase  -Data Source: Type
>      the name of the DSN you created On The Security Page  -Map a login to
>      the Remote User and provide the Remote Users Password  -Click Add
>      under Local server login to remote server login mappings:  -Select a
>      Local Login From the drop down box  -Type the name of the Remote User 
>      -Type the password for the Remote User
> 5. Change the Properties of the Provider MSDASQL Expand Providers -> Right Click MSDASQL -> Select Properties  -Enable Nested queries 
>      -Enable Level zero only (this one's the kicker)  -Enable Allow inprocess  -Enable Supports 'Like' operator
> 6. Change settings in SQL Server Surface Area Configuration for Features  -Enable OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE support.
> 7. Change settings in SQL Server Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections  -Enable Local and Remote connections via
>      TCP/IP and named pipes
> 8. Stop SQL Server and SQL Server Agent
> 9. Start SQL Server and SQL Server Agent

I didn't find I needed to restart the SQL server.